# React Event Handlers with TypeScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am trying to pass a delete function as props to a child component.
When a button is clicked in the child component, an id should be passed as an argument. I couldn't figure out the type for this function.
Please see the code below:

```
const App: React.FC = () => {
  
  const deleteHandle = (id: string) => {
          dispatch(deleteItem(id));
  };

  return (
  <ChildComponent deleteHandle={deleteHandle}/>
  )
}
```

Child Component:

```
interface ChildProps {
  deleteHandle: (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) => void;
}

const ChildComponent = ({deleteHandle}: ChildProps) => {

  return (
<button onClick={deleteHandle('id')} >Delete<button/> 
 
)}
```

deleteHandle should be both a React.MouseEvent and has id type string.
How should I write this?

Comment: Why should `deleteHandle` be a `React.MouseEvent`? I don't see you use `event` parameter.

Comment: Maybe `<button onClick={() => deleteHandle('id')} >Delete<button/>` is what you are looking for.

Comment: And `deleteHandle: (id: string) => void;`

Comment: Since it will be fired onClick,  I thought it should be a React.MouseEvent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can update your `deleteHandle` to take in two arguments, this way you will be able to both have access to the event and any argument you want.

```
const App: React.FC = () => {
  const deleteHandle = (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>, id: string) => {
    dispatch(deleteItem(id));
  };

  return (
    <ChildComponent deleteHandle={deleteHandle}/>
  )
}


interface ChildProps {
  deleteHandle: (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>, id: string) => void;
}

const ChildComponent = ({deleteHandle}: ChildProps) => {

  return (
    <button onClick={e => deleteHandle(e, 'id')} >Delete<button/> 
)}
```

Comment: Thank you this solved the problem. Also removing event type also solved the issue. It seems I don't need event type here.